# Divs appearing all at once rather than individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of divs within a container. I want these divs to appear at the top of the div, one by one, using the fade-in and then fade-out effect. At the moment I am using a for loop to try and achieve this, but it is having a strange result. Instead of iterating through the class elements, it is displaying them all at once. I have been trying to figure out the problem, but I just cant seem to find the issue.

```js
var customerComments = $(".customercomment");

for (var i = 0; i < customerComments.length; i++) {
  $(customerComments[i]).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(customerComments[i]).delay(600).fadeOut("slow");
  })
}
```

```css
/*STYLING FOR TESTIMONIALS SECTION */

#customerreviews {
  background-color: #5a2a27;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.customercomment {
  margin-top: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px 120px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.customercomment p {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.customercomment h4 {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.location {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="testimonials">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>TESTIMONIALS FROM OUR MEMBERS</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="customerreviews">
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"What I find to be the best thing about Elite Fitness Gym, other than the facilities they have to offer, is their overall service and the fact that they do not tie you down to a contract. They make things as easy as possible, inside and outside
            the gym, in every way!"</p>
          <h4>Rachel Smith<span class="location"> (Manchester)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I am blown away at how cheap the membership is and how much we get back in return. I take full advantage of the MMA classes they offer! I also like the fact that there is more than one class per week, which offers me flexibility - something
            I need with my busy schedule."</p>
          <h4>Darren Wise<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I am really impressed with the amount of equipment Elite Fitness Gym offer. Even during rush hour I rarely find myself waiting around for equipment. They have certainly done a fantastic job there. I like to keep my workouts short but intense,
            so its a great benefit for me."</p>
          <h4>Arif Akhtar<span class="location"> (Leeds)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I've been around the block with a number of gyms, but what sets Elite Fitness Gym apart from the rest is their ability to always improve on their service and benefits. I dont feel the need to look elsewhere because this gym is always growing
            and taking fantastic, ongoing care of its members."</p>
          <h4>Jason Hardy<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I am a big lover of swimming and the facilities that Elite Fitness Gym offer, not just with resistance workouts, but also with cardio, is what encouraged me to join in the first place. I must say that I am so happy with the decision as they
            really do have great facilities here."</p>
          <h4>Michelle Rousey<span class="location"> (Birmingham)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"The thing I benefit from most about Elite Fitness Gym is their timings. They are open 24 hours a day so it gives me a chance to drop in and do my workout just before going to work on my nightshifts. I am grateful to be able to attend such a
            great gym during those hours of the day."</p>
          <h4>Jermaine Clarke<span class="location"> (Bristol)</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Side note: `$(customerComments[i])` is taking a jquery object, breaking out a single element, and then turning it back into a jquery object.  Just use `customerComments.eq(i)` instead for the same result.

Comment: Also for some insight into your thought process, what part of the logic did you think would keep them from all fading in at the same time?

Comment: I am still fairly new to programming, but what I was expecting by using the loop, was on each occassion it would target the 0 index, then first 1index of the dom collection. My thinking behind it was that once it is done putting that effect to the first element containing the class name, it will then move onto the next. Isnt this how it works with loops in javascript? Or is it different when using them with jquery? Sorry, as mentioned I am still quite new to programming so I realize my undestanding at times can be a bit of a mess

Comment: if you want each div to appear in sequence, you'll need to somehow "chain" the asynchronous animations in such a way that div "n" waits until div "n-1" animation is complete. Does your version of jquery have "jquery promise" property on the return value of `fadeIn` function?

Comment: The fadeIn/fadeOut method are non-blocking methods.  They create entries on an internal animation queue that jQuery uses to perform the animations.  The loops will continue to run while those are being processed.  So, for the solution.  Do you want the logic to move on after the previous one has faded in, or move on after the previous one has faded in *and* out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is using the promises available in the returned value of the animation functions, and chain them using array#reduce

```js
var customerComments = $(".customercomment");

function doit() {
    [].reduce.call(customerComments, function(p, unused, i) {
        var $comment = customerComments.eq(i);
        return p.then(function() {
            return $comment.fadeIn("slow").promise().then(function() {
                return $comment.delay(600).fadeOut("slow").promise();
            });
        });
    }, $.when()).then(doit);
}
doit();
```

```css
/*STYLING FOR TESTIMONIALS SECTION */

#customerreviews {
  background-color: #5a2a27;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.customercomment {
  margin-top: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px 120px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.customercomment p {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.customercomment h4 {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.location {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="testimonials">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>TESTIMONIALS FROM OUR MEMBERS</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="customerreviews">
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"What I find to be the best thing about Elite Fitness Gym, other than the facilities they have to offer, is their overall service and the fact that they do not tie you down to a contract. They make things as easy as possible, inside and outside
            the gym, in every way!"</p>
          <h4>Rachel Smith<span class="location"> (Manchester)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I am blown away at how cheap the membership is and how much we get back in return. I take full advantage of the MMA classes they offer! I also like the fact that there is more than one class per week, which offers me flexibility - something
            I need with my busy schedule."</p>
          <h4>Darren Wise<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I am really impressed with the amount of equipment Elite Fitness Gym offer. Even during rush hour I rarely find myself waiting around for equipment. They have certainly done a fantastic job there. I like to keep my workouts short but intense,
            so its a great benefit for me."</p>
          <h4>Arif Akhtar<span class="location"> (Leeds)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I've been around the block with a number of gyms, but what sets Elite Fitness Gym apart from the rest is their ability to always improve on their service and benefits. I dont feel the need to look elsewhere because this gym is always growing
            and taking fantastic, ongoing care of its members."</p>
          <h4>Jason Hardy<span class="location"> (London)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"I am a big lover of swimming and the facilities that Elite Fitness Gym offer, not just with resistance workouts, but also with cardio, is what encouraged me to join in the first place. I must say that I am so happy with the decision as they
            really do have great facilities here."</p>
          <h4>Michelle Rousey<span class="location"> (Birmingham)</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="customercomment text-center">
          <p>"The thing I benefit from most about Elite Fitness Gym is their timings. They are open 24 hours a day so it gives me a chance to drop in and do my workout just before going to work on my nightshifts. I am grateful to be able to attend such a
            great gym during those hours of the day."</p>
          <h4>Jermaine Clarke<span class="location"> (Bristol)</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution Jaromanda! I do apologise but is there also a way I can loop this method?

Comment: oh, you want it to continuously loop through those divs?

Comment: Indeed Jaromanda, sorry if i wasnt clear about that in my OP, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following and it fades the divs in one by one. While it does not use the fadeOut function, it still uses the fadeIn function.

```
$($(".customercomment").get().reverse()).each(function(fadeInDiv) {
     $(this).delay(fadeInDiv * 600).fadeIn(1000);
});
```